# Start IIS Express using /path from command line with HTTPS?

Tags: command-line, https, iis-express

Is it possible to start IIS Express from the command line using the /path argument and include an HTTPS binding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Following link would help you in configuring https port (especially read "Making an SSL Cert, hooking it up to IIS Express and making it Trusted" from this link )
   https://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx
2. When /path command line option is used, IIS Express uses the template appliationhost.config file located in %programfiles%\IIS Express\AppServer (on 64-bit machine %programfiles(x86)%\IIS Express\AppServer). Edit binding element in this configuration file as shown below (change the protocol to 'https')

   ```
   <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
   ```
3. Now from the IIS Express installation folder, run `iisexpress.exe /path:"<path-to-your-web-application>" /port:<HTTPS-port-configured-in-step-1>`

Comment: Would this work for HTTP and HTTPS binding at the same time?  Just add another <binding> node?

Comment: No. It does not work... Probably you should use /config command line switch.

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to do it completely from the command link without editing the configuration.  Sound like it can't be done.

Answer (score 12):

Another one for the scripts section:

```
IisExpressAdminCmd setupSslUrl -url:https://localhost:44308 -UseSelfSigned

appcmd add site /name:"MySite" /bindings:https/*:44308:localhost /physicalPath:"C:\MySite"

iisexpress /site:MySite
```

Those commands are in the `C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\` directory.

Comment: This is great. What if you have multiple sites? How to start them in in the same pool?

Answer (score 2):

I've struggle with this too. Its not quite the pristine solution you want but you can add a new site to the default iisexpress config via the command line:

```
APPCMD add site /name:MyNewSite /bindings:"http/*:81:" /physicalPath:"C:\MyNewSite"
```

You'll want to target the appcmd.exe in c:\program files (x86)\iis express

After adding it you can then launch iisexpress the conventional way using iisexpress.exe targeting the site you just added to the config.

[Manipulating Objects with ADD, SET, and DELETE](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/114/getting-started-with-appcmdexe/#Manipulating)

You need to "allow" iisexpress to serve ssl as well.

[Working with SSL at Development Time is easier with IISExpress](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx)

Still it's probably just easier/cleaner to write your own custom config file with the bindings you want and load the site using that. More control that way.